# Esclarecimento sobre solução para o Erro: Apache Shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: xampp

Instalei o  XAMPP recentemente , no painel ao iniciar o serviço  do apache foram exibidas a seguinte mensagem de erro

```
09:04:36  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
09:04:36  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
09:04:36  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
09:04:36  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
09:04:36  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
09:04:36  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
09:04:36  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
09:08:10  [Apache]  Problem detected!
09:08:10  [Apache]  Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
09:08:10  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
09:08:10  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
09:08:10  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

Para solucionar este problema consultei este [vídeo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8pOkmxQ0Co) no qual o autor adiciona o trecho de código abaixo em seu arquivo `httpd.conf` :

```
#Listen [::]:80
```

Isto resolveu o problema mas gostaria de saber o que isso significa exatamente ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando `httpd` é iniciado, ele se conecta a alguma porta e endereço na máquina local e aguarda para receber requisições. Isso faz com que que o servidor aceite conexões na porta 80 para uma interface e porta. `[::]` significa que é para qualquer `IP`, que no seu caso, qualquer `IP` na porta 80. Por padrão, ele escuta a todos os endereços na máquina. No entanto, ele pode precisar ser configurado para escutar em alguns portas específicas, ou somente em endereços selecionados, ou uma combinação de ambos.

#### Detalhes

- [Binding to Addresses and Ports](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/bind.html)